# Angular 4 - change color dependent on value

Tags: angular

I'm working with Angular 4 and I have a problem with conditional style changing.
I have a table and values in it. I need the values in a column to be changed depending if the value is greater or smaller than zero.
For example: if the value is 123, then its color should be green. If the value is -123, then its color should be red.

There is fragment of my code below, but it doesn't work like I'd like to:

```html
<mat-table>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="availableBalance">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Available balance</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" *ngIf="row.availableBalance > 0" [style.color]="'red'"> {{row.availableBalance}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
</mat-table>
```

Do you have any solutions? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You could use ngClass for this. https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

```
<mat-table>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="availableBalance">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Available balance</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"
         [ngClass]="{
            'positive' : row.availableBalance > 0,
            'negative' : row.availableBalance < 0
         }"
      >{{row.availableBalance}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
</mat-table>
```

In your CSS:

```
.positive {
    background-color: green;
}

.negative {
    background-color: red;
}
```

This will leave 0 unstyled.

Very simple Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z2hnrn

Comment: this for me just highlights the cell. is there a way to expand this to the row?

Comment: Pretty sure you can do that in the `<mat-row>` element at the bottom. Something like `<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [ngClass]="{'positive' : row.availableBalance > 0, 'negative' : row.availableBalance < 0}"></mat-row>`

Answer (score 15):

Use ngStyle with a method as expression. Add the following method to your component:

```
public getColor(balance: number): string{
   return balance > 0 ? "green" : "red";
}
```

And in template use it as expression:

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" *ngIf="row.availableBalance > 0" [ngStyle]="{'color': getColor(row.availableBalance)}"> {{row.availableBalance}}
</mat-cell>
```