# Change the colour of printed value in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7, ng-class

I am trying to call an API and display the json in my front end.

I wanted to change the color of a particular value called {{status}}. When the status is available i want it as green, and when not available as red.

I tried using a class, but I failed to do it.  any lead would be helpful.

this is the code i have tried so far.

app.html

```
<h1>Demo</h1>
<ul>
<ol>
  <li *ngFor="let ex of ex$ ">
        <a>id: {{ex.id}}</a>
        <a>Status: {{ex.status}}</a>
        <span class: "changecolor">{{ex.status}}</span>
        <a>address: {{ex.address}}</a>

  </li>
</ol>
</ul>
```

In css file

**

```
.changecolor{

color: green;

}
```

**

EDIT:

html

```
<div [ngClass]="ex.status === 'available'? 'green':'red'">Status: {{ex.status}}</div>
```

css

```
  .green {
  color: yellow;
}
.red {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `ngClass`, per the tag? Have you tried using correct HTML syntax (`attr="value"`)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe     I am new here with these framwork. Any example supporting would be really helpful.

Comment: How do you know that the status is available? Is it a string with the value "available"?

Comment: One of those suggestions doesn't relate to the framework. For the other, see https://angular.io/tutorial.

Comment: @Mikz try like this `<div [ngClass]="[condition ? 'first' : 'second']"></div>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4 - change color dependent on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433827/angular-4-change-color-dependent-on-value)

Comment: @ConnorsFan my status value is a string in a json file. after the service call, I am printing it in my UI

Comment: @Abhishek actually, from my html file, you can see that {{ex.status}} is providing me two values, available and not available. How can I provide condition here ?

Comment: @Mikz `ex.status === available ` second class apply only condition is false.

Comment: @Abhishek Can you check the edit ? I tried and it dint work

Comment: That wouldn't work, no, the syntax is wrong. *Read the documentation*.

Comment: @Mikz check it on link (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c9e1kx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). its working let me know its work for you or not

Comment: @Abhishek It works !!! But I just want the condition to be coloured. For eg: now its showing status: available ; completely in green. I want only available to be in green.. How can I customise it?

Comment: @Mikz try `<div *ngFor="let ab of abc">
  <div>Status: <span [ngClass]="ab.status === 'available'? 'green':'red'">{{ab.status}}</span></div>
</div>`

Comment: @Mikz also check on link (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c9e1kx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have add condition based on class if condition is `true` show your primary class other wise secondary one

Html:

```
<div *ngFor="let ex of ex$">
  <div>Status: <span [ngClass]="ex.status === 'available'? 'green':'red'">{{ex.status}}</span></div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.green {
  color: green;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
```