# How to vary background color based on value

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm listing out a table that has the results of a tournament. I have the final placements, as well as the original seeds for each team in the tournament. I'm adding a small bubble with a +/- of how the final placement compares to the original seeding. I'd like to make the background get a darker red as the team did worse, and darker green as the team did better.

Example:

```
Team A finished 1st and was seeded 3rd -> light green
Team B finish 2nd and was seeded 30th -> dark green
Team C finished 10th was seeded 8th -> light red
Team D finish 30th and was seeded 1st -> dark red
```

I'd like to set a limit obviously for how dark/light the colors get, so teams that out/under performed past a certain amount would all have the same dark tone.

My site is built using Angular, but is this possible to do with just some simple CSS?

Here is a picture from another site that has this already implemented:

[image: screenshot of example website]

As you can see, the final finish is listed on the left, and how well they performed in comparison to their original seeding is on the right. Blank signifies Seed == Finish

Comment: Hello. What have you tried so far? Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the Help section.

Comment: How are the placements and seeds stored?

Comment: Duplicate of [Angular 4 - change color dependent on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433827/angular-4-change-color-dependent-on-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array for the colors

TS:

```
colors = [{ finished: "1st", color: "light green" }, { finished: "30th", color: "dark green"}]
```

Loop through your data in a table (or how you prefer) and add `ngStyle`:

```html
<table>
  <th>Team</th>
  <th>Finished</th>
  <tr *ngFor="let res of colors" [ngStyle]="{'background':getColor(res.finished)}">
    <td>res.whateveryourfieldiscalled</td>
    <td>res.whateveryourfieldiscalled</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And then add it with a ts `getColor` method:

```ts
getColor(finished) {
 return this.colors.filter(item => item.finished === finished)[0].color
}
```

Comment: This is a cool answer, but not quite what I'm looking for. I don't want to just make 1st place green and 30th red. The color should correlate to if the team broke seed or not. I'll add a screenshot of an example I found on another site.

Comment: actually--I think this will still work, I just need to adjust the logic for getColor.

Comment: Are the `<td>` inner contents missing curly braces? Also, what happens if the `filter` returns an empty array? Is it worthwhile to check for that before trying to access `[0].color`?